# Get value from span to Django view

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have this javascript that gets longitude and latitude from a Google Map:

```
<script>
    // Get element references
    var confirmBtn = document.getElementById('confirmPosition');
    var onClickPositionView = document.getElementById('onClickPositionView');
    var latonIdlePositionView = document.getElementById('latOnIdlePositionView');
    var longonIdlePositionView = document.getElementById('longOnIdlePositionView');
  
    // Initialize locationPicker plugin
    var lp = new locationPicker('map', {
      setCurrentPosition: true, // You can omit this, defaults to true
    }, {
      zoom: 15 // You can set any google map options here, zoom defaults to 15
    });
    // Listen to map idle event, listening to idle event more accurate than listening to ondrag event
    google.maps.event.addListener(lp.map, 'idle', function (event) {
      // Get current location and show it in HTML
      var location = lp.getMarkerPosition();
      latOnIdlePositionView.innerHTML = location.lat;
      longOnIdlePositionView.innerHTML = location.lng;
    });
  </script>
```

This is the HTML I have for a user to define his or her location:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'geolocate' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="card-header">
        <div class="float-start">
        <h3 class="card-title">Me localiser</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body no-padding">
        <div id="map"></div>
        <p>Latitude: <span id="latOnIdlePositionView"></span> Longitude: <span id="longOnIdlePositionView" ></span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer text-end">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Mettre à jour</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is my view:

```
def geolocate(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        lat = request.POST.get('lat_kw')
        long = request.POST.get('long_kw')

        caccount = Account.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
        caccount.lat = lat
        caccount.long = long
        caccount.save()
        return redirect('monprofil')
```

What I want to do is to get the value form the spans latOnIdlePositionView and longOnIdlePositionView and put them in my view.

I know how to do this if I have data in an input field (using name), but I do not know how to do this using spans.

Comment: Use a `<input type='hidden' name='lat_kw' value='' id='hidden_lat_kw'>`, then using your JavaScript, fill in the hidden input value, `document.getElementById('hidden_lat_kw').value = location.lat;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to the comment by [@raphael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10951070/raphael)

Add this inside form tag in HTML

```
<input type='hidden' name='lat_kw' id='lat_kw' value=''>
<input type='hidden' name='long_kw' id='long_kw' value=''>
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById('lat_kw').value = location.lat;
document.getElementById('long_kw').value = location.lng;
```

Then you good to go

Comment: Thank you! I did this at the end (replaced innerHTML by value. Now I need to do the opposite, instead of having the map loading the default location, I want it to put the lat and long data from the database. How can I change this in JavaScript?

Comment: I have the same problem but the hidden type stop me from showing the value even if I replaced the value it still impossible to view the desired value because it's "hidden" any help ?

Comment: So change it to `type="text"` if you want it to be visible